# Maintain the font of the whole plot (x and y axis), but keeping the labels on top of the graph smaller so they dont overlap

Tags: python, fonts, label, seaborn, relplot

Basically I am using different columns to plot my data using seaborn.
I use sns.set_context("talk") so the font is big enough to be read properly. However, since the specifications of the parameters are quite long, the text on top of the graphs overlap. The quick solution is change the font sns.set_context("paper") or apply any scale to reduce the size. However, all the font gets reduced including the x and y axis. Making it very difficult to read. and I want to keep x and y axis at that font.

Do you know if I can change the size of the text that overlap, but keeping the x and y text at that font?
Or tell seaborn relplot to make a line break on the labels on top?

I tried to reduce size, but everything get reduces.
I tried a line break, but since I dont introduce the labels, I cant.
I tried to individually increase the size of x and y font, but since I have 16 graphs, it makes it annoying and long.

`sns.set_style("ticks") sns.set_context("talk") ax1=sns.relplot( data=df,x="Impeller speed (rpm)", style="Mineral content (g/g fibre)",y="Power draw (W)", palette=palette,ci=68,kind="line",markers=True,size="size (mm)",hue="Formulation", col="size (mm)",row="Mineral content (g/g fibre)") plt.show()`

| Formulation | size (mm) | Mineral content (g/g fibre) | Imepeller speed (rpm) | Power draw (W) | Viscosity (Pas) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Water | 1 | 0 | 200 | 20 | 0.00159 |
| Water | 1 | 0 | 300 | 21 | 0.00159 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 200 | 22 | 0.0018 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 300 | 25 | 0.0018 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 200 | 26 | 0.0059 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 300 | 29 | 0.0059 |
| Water | 4 | 0 | 200 | 22 | 0.00159 |
| Water | 4 | 1 | 300 | 32 | 0.00159 |
| C | 1 | 0 | 200 | 20 | 0.1059 |
| C | 1 | 0 | 300 | 25 | 0.1059 |

[image]

Comment: You can add `plt.tight_layout()` just before `plt.show()` to avoid text overlaps between subplots.

Comment: Thank you. That is an alternative. However, what it makes, it makes the graph bigger so the text do not overlap. This leads to a small text size (since I use this graph in a presentation). Ideally, I'd like to keep the size of the axis big enough so it can be read easily. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ax in ax1.axes.flat: # Iterate over each axes object
    # Change the fontsize of each title 
    ax.set_title(ax.get_title(), fontsize='small')  #ax.get_title function returns the title text string.
```

Comment: Let me know if you need further help this works as you requested on dummy data I tried.

Comment: That is great Cem! It solved the issue just as I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JavierRodriguez No problem at all happy to help, have a great day!